# How to get a scanned PDF to Excel via OCR?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr, tesseract

The code i have used is :-

```
import os
import tempfile
import subprocess

def ocr(path):

    process = subprocess.Popen(
        ['tesseract', path, 'stdout'],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE
    )

    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

    if stderr: # handle errors anyway you want, I'll just raise exception as example
        raise RuntimeError(f'tesserect failed with: {stderr.decode()}')
    else: # success
        return stdout.decode()

str = ocr(r'C:/Users/renu.sharma/Documents/Ragini/File.pdf')
print(str)
```

The error is :-

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-6838d49f4a48> in <module>
     18         return stdout.decode()
     19 
---> 20 str = ocr(r'C:/Users/renu.sharma/Documents/Ragini/File.pdf')
     21 #print(str)
     22 

<ipython-input-41-6838d49f4a48> in ocr(path)
      8         ['tesseract', path, 'stdout'],
      9         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
---> 10         stderr=subprocess.PIPE
     11     )
     12 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    767                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
    768                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 769                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    770         except:
    771             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
   1170                                          env,
   1171                                          os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None else None,
-> 1172                                          startupinfo)
   1173             finally:
   1174                 # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have also tried the below code,

```
import tika
from tika import parser
import os
import re
mpath = r'C:/Users/renu.sharma/Documents/Ragini/File.pdf'
onlyfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(mpath) if f.endswith('.pdf')]
onlyfiles.sort()
onlyfiles = [os.path.join(mpath, name) for name in onlyfiles]
for s in onlyfiles:
    fileReader = parser.from_file(s)
    rawList = fileReader['content'].splitlines()
    rawList_1 = list(filter(None, rawList))
    print(rawList_1)
```

This is also giving the belwo error

```
[WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:/Users/renu.sharma/Documents/Ragini/File.pdf'
```

I have a scanned PDF of various business cards & I am trying to get these details to Excel.

Below is the code I have tried so far,

```
import os
import tempfile
import subprocess

def ocr(path):
    temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)

    process = subprocess.Popen(['tesseract', path, temp.name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    process.communicate()

    with open(temp.name + '.txt', 'r') as handle:
        contents = handle.read()

    os.remove(temp.name + '.txt')
    os.remove(temp.name)

    return contents

str = ocr(r'C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\XXXX\file_Name')
print(str)
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Seems to be a very simple one, but I am unable to figure out what's wrong with this.

Comment: do you need to use a `tempfile`? I believe on Windows other processes may not be able to read from it.

Comment: Is there any other way then using tempfile ? I have multiple PDFs & need to extract the text from them, Is it possible to achieve it way other than mentioned above, i would be glad to learn that !!

Answer (score 0):

I would just avoid the temporary file altogether, [you can make tesseract write to standard out by passing `stdout`](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/tesseract.1.asc#inout-arguments), so you can just do something like:

```
import os
import tempfile
import subprocess

def ocr(path):

    process = subprocess.Popen(
        ['tesseract', path, 'stdout'],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE
    )

    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

    if stderr: # handle errors anyway you want, I'll just raise exception as example
        raise RuntimeError(f'tesserect failed with: {stderr.decode()}')
    else: # success
        return stdout.decode()
```

Comment: Still showing the below error:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: @renu post the *full error message* showing the code you are using.

Comment: I have edited the question with the entire code i am using along with the whole error message